# Context is reinitialized every time I change page

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

I have defined my context to store the page theme mode ("light" or "dark") as follows:

```
import {createContext, useState} from "react";

const SessionContext = createContext({
    mode: [],
    changeMode: () => {
    },
});

export function SessionContextProvider(props) {
    const [sessionMode, setSessionMode] = useState("dark");

    function ChangeModeHandler() {
        setSessionMode(sessionMode === "light" ? "dark" : "light")
    }

    const context = {
        mode: sessionMode,
        changeMode: ChangeModeHandler,
    };

    return (
        <SessionContext.Provider value={context}>
            {props.children}
        </SessionContext.Provider>
    );
}

export default SessionContext;
```

It is correctly stored and logged. Nevertheless, when I change the page, it gets always redefined as "dark", the value defined by default.

I am simply importing it at the beginning of every page as follows:

```
const sessionCtx = useContext(SessionContext);
console.log("Session mode: " + sessionCtx.mode)
const mode = sessionCtx.mode;
```

How can we avoid this situation and ensure that "light" will be respected across pages?

Edit: I am wrapping the app as follows in index.js:

```
import {SessionContextProvider} from "./store/session-context";

        <SessionContextProvider>
            <CssBaseline>
                <BrowserRouter>
                    <App/>
                </BrowserRouter>
            </CssBaseline>
        </SessionContextProvider>
```

Comment: Can you show how are you wrapping the context? I mean, are you wrapping the whole app once or doing in each page?

Comment: I´ve edited and included it

Comment: Maybe try changing the position of the SessionContextProvider to wrap only App ?

Comment: I did it but is still reinitializing the context value

Comment: you have <ThemeProvider theme={lightTheme}>
        <SessionContextProvider>
if you are trying to change SessionContext what is ThemeProvider about?

Comment: Well, good question, It was there from a previous config, and as it is not anymore used I deleted it and edited the question. But still, I have the same Context reinitializing the result.

Comment: then you need show how and where you are changing the value

Comment: and also to understand what exactly "when I change the page" means

Comment: When I change the endpoint URL. For example, from /home to /testpage. Basically, when I access the different Routes in App.js

Comment: assuming everything else is correct (can't tell without seeing the full code), check if you don't reload the page (you can do it in the browser console)

Comment: Maybe you should create a reproducible example in a sandbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. It was not related at all with the context or how it is configured but to the Links.

I moved from this setup (using MUI Link):

```
import {Link} from "@mui/material";

    <ListItemButton
        component={Link}
        href="/historic"
        sx={{textDecoration: "none"}}
    >
        <ListItemIcon>
            <DashboardIcon/>
        </ListItemIcon>
        <ListItemText
            primary="Histórico"
            primaryTypographyProps={{fontSize: fontSizeMenu}}
        />
    </ListItemButton>
```

To this other one (using "react-router-dom" Link):

```
import {Link} from "react-router-dom"

<Link
    to="/historic"
    style={{
        textDecoration: "none",
        color: "inherit"
    }}
>
    <ListItemButton>
        <ListItemIcon>
            <DashboardIcon/>
        </ListItemIcon>
        <ListItemText
            primary="Histórico"
            primaryTypographyProps={{fontSize: fontSizeMenu}}
        />
    </ListItemButton>
</Link>
```

While the first one shows the context reinitializing behaviour explained, the second one respects the context values stored (and it moves among endpoints faster).

I would appreciate an explanation of why it is this way as a note to this answer, but I guess that the context is somehow only considered by library "react-router-dom".